# How do I upgrade from Hyperledger Fabric 1.1 to 1.4.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have an existing project in production which is running on Hyperledger Fabric version 1.1 . How do i perform an upgrade to 1.4.2?

Hyperledger Fabric documentation only cover moving from v1.3 to v1.4.x or from an earlier version of v1.4.x to a later version to v1.4.x.

I need any reference material or link which can help me to upgrade to 1.4.2 from 1.1

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything exactly regarding this on the internet, but here are the steps which worked for me in a ubuntu environment:

1. Copy your entire network directory(which has all fabric related files) to a convenient location.
2. Stop & remove the currently running fabric containers & images:

   - docker stop $(docker ps -a | grep fabric | cut -c1-12)
   - docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep fabric | cut -c1-12)
   - docker rmi $( docker images | grep fabric | cut -c143-157)

     > [column numbers for **cut** may vary as per your container name lengths]

> Since it is a prod setup, I am assuming it may have other containers also running. Therefore, exercise caution while removing containers. The script network.sh will remove all crypto-configs, ledgers & uses **-f** option to remove which may affect other containers. So instead of directly executing **./network.sh -m down**, it is safe to grep only fabric related containers, images and remove them.

3. Go inside the location where the network folder was copied and Replace `CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL` with `FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC` inside /docker-compose-base/docker-compose-base.yaml file. Otherwise, the following warning will occur while executing peer commands:

> `2019-06-14 12:14:26.605 CEST [main] InitCmd -> WARN 001 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable
>   2019-06-14 12:14:26.611 CEST [main] SetOrdererEnv -> WARN 002 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable`

4. Start the network:

   ./network.sh -m recreate